# Неправильный подсчет голосов

Tags: дефект, поддержка, статус-так-задумано, выборы

Заметил нечто следующее:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

16 - 22 != 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Там и в соседнем не показывается отрицательное. Предположу, что решили вместо отрицательных значений показывать нули. И ещё единицы, если сам голосовал.

Comment: [Не-а](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVSAx.png).

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, опоздал, я уже дополнил. Там 0, -1 или +1 после обновления страницы. Если сначала запросить голоса, а потом проголосовать, то вообще реальное покажут временно.

Comment: Ага, а если голосунуть против показывается истинный счет...

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, а страницу обнови?

Comment: угу...................

Comment: [статус-так-задумано] ?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor [статус-так-задумано-но-всё-равно-глючит] :D

Comment: ;) ;) ;) ;D ...

Comment: Жаль тока слишком длинно, а то ты б мог сделать ;)

Comment: Это чтобы не расстраивать кандидатов?) А чего на обычные вопросы/ответы так не сделали? Может есть где-то обсуждение на эту тему почитать?

Comment: @dIm0n, чтобы расстраивать нерадивых пользователей :-D ну и медальки чтобы дать

Answer (score 2):

Есть такой оформленный баг на MSE [Election page shows zero votes instead of negative until I view vote count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112127/339911). Закрытый в свою очередь как дубликат на фича-реквест [Do not show the score for users during primaries](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76412/339911). При этом реквест даже не помечен красной меткой `[status-completed]`, но раз уж фактически ситуация имеет место быть, значит он исполнен. Суть в следующем.

Автор заявляет, что наличие отрицательного рейтинга у поста кандидата автоматически формирует у него негативное восприятие этого кандидата, что даже не хочется читать что же он там написал о себе и тем более видеть его модератором. С другой стороны он может даже захотеть его подбодрить и поставить плюс (просто чтобы уменьшить негативную составляющую). Короче говоря, автор не может сформировать независимо своё мнение о кандидате, если сразу видит отрицательный рейтинг. Имхо, это проблема автора, но раз уж большинство с ним согласилось (сейчас там +67/-8 на вопросе), и более того, сайт так и работает (отрицательный рейтинг не показывается), то, вероятно он в этом не одинок. Я его точку зрения не разделяю. Хотя если обратить внимание на заголовок "Do not show the score for users during primaries", а не на сам текст, то предложение может быть о том, чтобы не показывать рейтинг вовсе, ни отрицательный, ни положительный на этапе предварительного голосования, и тут в целом можно было бы с ним и согласиться.

Comment: Согласен, вообще не показывать это правильно

Comment: А толку тогда от предварительного голосования? Предлагаете в конце показывать, кто на каком месте?